# removeEventListener remains active even at wide widths

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

When the screen is smaller than 1021px, I try to add an eventListener on all navbar buttons. But when I return to a screen larger than 1020 px the eventListener remains active and I don't want it to remain active.

How should I modify the code to get what I want?

```
function navBarPhoneScreenClickEffect() {

    const allPhoneTabsNav = document.querySelectorAll('div.phone-tab');
    let vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);

    function test() {
        console.log('test');
    }
            
    if (vw <= 1020) {
        
        for (let i = 0; i < allPhoneTabsNav.length; i++) {
            allPhoneTabsNav[i].addEventListener('click', test)
        }
        
    } else {
        
        for (let i = 0; i < allPhoneTabsNav.length; i++) {
            allPhoneTabsNav[i].removeEventListener('click', test)
        }
        
    }

}

window.addEventListener('resize', navBarPhoneScreenClickEffect, false);
```

Comment: Obvious stuff first: are you sure that `vw` has a value > 1020? Since you grab the DOM elements fresh on every invocation, are you sure that you're getting the same list of them to iterate on each invocation?

Comment: You are creating a new test function. That will break

Comment: "Obvious stuff first: are you sure that vw has a value > 1020?"
yes, I'm sure about that aspect. I'm sure that the screen is much bigger and I checked with console.log(vw).

" are you sure that you're getting the same list of them to iterate on each invocation?"
it is the same list. I also checked with console.log(allPhoneTabsNav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the same function reference to `removeEventListener` as was originally pased to `addEventListener`. Since `test` is defined inside the function `navBarPhoneScreenClickEffect`, it's a different function each time `navBarPhoneScreenClickEffect` is called. Declare it outside to fix this.

```js
function test() {
    console.log('test');
}
function navBarPhoneScreenClickEffect() { 
    // ...
}
```